MariaDB building dynamic JSON_ARRAY conditionally, prevent casting JSON_OBJECT to string and double-quoting
USE CASE: We want to create a JSON_ARRAY containing various JSON_OBJECTS. These objects are added if (and only if) certain conditions are true. If they are false, then that object should not be added to the array. Nor an empty string nor a NULL value.
PROBLEM: Working with strings, it's rather common to do a:
CONCAT(
         IF( <condition1>, 'a', '')
        ,IF( <condition2>, 'b', '')
        ,IF( <condition3>, 'c', '')
    ) as `result`;

, where concatenation of an empty string effectively serves as a means to say 'no data to append'. But if we attempt that with JSON functions:
JSON_ARRAY(
         IF( <condition1>, JSON_OBJECT('one','ok'), NULL)
        ,IF( <condition2>, JSON_OBJECT('two','ok'), NULL)
        ,IF( <condition3>, JSON_OBJECT('three','ok'), NULL)
    ) as `result`;

Then the resulting array would include NULL values for conditions that are false. And we'd end up with JSON like [{"a":"a"}, null, null]

We can't do:
SELECT JSON_ARRAY( 'a', CASE WHEN <condition> THEN JSON_OBJECT('one', 'ok') END) AS test;
because when the condition is false, the CASE will by default return NULL, and NULL gets added to the json_array.

We also can't do:
SELECT JSON_ARRAY( 'a', IF(<condition>, JSON_OBJECT('one', 'ok'),'') ) AS test;
because this causes MariaDB to even cast the returned JSON_OBJECT to a string in cases where the condition is true. (I wonder if this would classify as a bug: though understandable, I think it's weird that the ELSE '' statement affects another branch's output data, explicitly quoting the object as a string instead of keeping the existing string representation)


SQL testcase results:
(Correct answers must match the desired outcome from the 'desired_result' column.)
WITH 
two_rows AS (SELECT '1' AS `type` UNION SELECT '2')

SELECT `type`
,IF(`type`=1,'["test", {"type": "1"}]','["test"]') AS `desired_result`
,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_ARRAY('test',IF(`type`='1',JSON_OBJECT('type',`type`),''))) AS `case_using_if_with_empty_string`
,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_ARRAY('test',CASE WHEN `type`='1' THEN JSON_OBJECT('type',`type`) END)) AS `case_using case_with_null_json_object`
,JSON_UNQUOTE(REPLACE(JSON_ARRAY('test', CASE WHEN `type`='1' THEN JSON_OBJECT('type', `type`) ELSE '*PLACEHOLDER*' END),', "*PLACEHOLDER*"','')) AS `case_using_string_stringreplace`
,JSON_UNQUOTE(REPLACE(JSON_ARRAY('test',IF(`type`='1',JSON_OBJECT('type',`type`),JSON_OBJECT('PLACEHOLDER','REMOVE'))),', {"PLACEHOLDER": "REMOVE"}','')) AS `case_using_json_objectstringreplace`
,CONCAT('["test"',IF(`type`='1',CONCAT(',',JSON_OBJECT('type',`type`)),''),']') AS `case_using_string_concat`
FROM two_rows

WORKAROUNDS:

We use the conditional construct with a placeholder JSON_OBJECT for else, and then use STRING_REPLACE to remove that object. BUT there is no guarantee that this replace will only happen at the root level of the JSON_ARRAY (any child-JSON_OBJECTs inside it that happen to have the placeholder too will be affected as well). This is demonstrated in column case_using_json_objectstringreplace.
Instead of using JSON_ARRAY, we just concat strings to form a JSON array. This is demonstrated in column case_using_string_concat, and seems to be the way to go.
We could split simple query into multiple / unioned queries and use JSON_ARRAYAGG. BUT this will end up (double)quoting the JSON-string of the object, and increase database load (due to multiple queries).
???

I don't see a straightforward, reliable and elegant solution for our problem. We're building a dynamic JSON object, so we cant use JSON_TABLE as we don't know the columns in advance.
Some thoughts:

It could help if there was a function that unescapes double-quoted JSON strings. I used JSON_UNQUOTE in the cases, but it doesn't deal with this mixed kind of JSON_OBJECT and quoted string.

It could help if there was a function that removes NULL values from a JSON_ARRAY.

Logically, it could make sense to allow a CASE WHEN without ELSE specified to act as 'nothing' for JSON_ARRAY. But this could break pre-existing queries.

Maybe if there are no simple solutions to this issue I'm facing, MariaDB could consider implementing a new function/construct of "NOTHING()" or "NO_JSON_OBJECT()", a placeholder function that:

Does not cause other conditional branches to be escaped to a string
Is considered a JSON_OBJECT but has no type (not a string), no value, is neither NULL nor NOT NULL, has count 0
and thus will not count as a value, nor will it be considered part of functions that support multiple arguments (i.e. (GROUP_)concat, JSON_ARRAY )

For example: JSON_ARRAY('test', IF(type='1',JSON_OBJECT('type',type),NOTHING())) . Now that would look great! :D


Takeaway: Working with JSON in MariaDB is a struggle. You can only exclusively use JSON functions with other JSON functions - when you add string related operations, MariaDB will cast the JSON object to a string, effectively double-escaping the data:
SET @json_obj = JSON_ARRAY(null,JSON_OBJECT('a', 'b'));
SELECT 
            JSON_ARRAY(null,JSON_OBJECT('a', 'b'))               -- source JSON_ARRAY
         , @json_obj                                             -- source JSON_ARRAY, stored in variable
         , JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(null,JSON_OBJECT('a', 'b'))) -- arrayagg directly over a JSON_ARRAY() works fine
         , JSON_ARRAYAGG(@json_obj);                             -- arrayagg over the same JSON_ARRAY stored in a variable will double-escape the data


I bailed on trying to find a solution for this because you don't have your actual use case and details matter.  I was able to come up with a function to remove nulls from an array, using json_table/subquery/json_arrayagg, but didn't get it fully working with all possible types of values in the array.  I suspect your problem can be addressed more directly using that json_table/subquery/json_arrayagg approach, but please do show your actual input data and schema (output of show create table yourtablename) with the variations you need to support.  at this point, just start with a new question
